# How to write integration test that writes to database, then retrieves the values, and validate all fields are populated correctly

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, integration-testing

I've been told to write an integration test that writes to the Postgres database, retrieves, then validates the fields are populated correctly. I'm not quite sure what to do here. Would I just write an `INSERT INTO` each table in the database with some dummy variables, and then check I can retrieve them and see if they're valid types? The test should execute when I do `mvn run package`.

I can't find any example code on how to do that.

Comment: Ask those who told you to about more details.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been told to write an integration test ... I'm not quite sure what to do here.

In general you should ask the one who assigned the task to you if you do not understand what to do. It's not a sign of weakness to ask for help :)

First things first. If you don't know what an Integration test(IT) is you should look it up. There are more than enough good explanations on the internet. E.g [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing)

> Would I just write an INSERT INTO each table ...

The main goal of a IT is to test that *all* your components work together as expected. If you would simply `INSERT INTO` you would not test the part of your application which writes into the database.
Your test should contain everything from `Controller` to `Repository`.

Lucky for you Spring Boot has an awesome ecosystem around IT.
There are also a lot of resources how to do this in detail. E.g. [Testing in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)

---

Also here is good article on how to use [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) for your IT:
[Write Spring Boot integration tests with Testcontainers (JUnit 4 & 5)](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/)

I really like to use Testcontainers for my IT but be warned that this is a more advanced level topic.